# Trying to preserve toggle state with JS

Tags: jquery, cookies

Am trying to preserve the toggle state for jQuery, am unable to set cookies as am not using `.toggle()`

My Code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#switch").click(function(event){
        if ($("#navbar").css("display")=='block') {
            $("#navbar").hide('fast');
            $(this).removeClass('close').addClass('open');
            $(this).children().children().html('+');
        } else {
            $("#navbar").show('fast');
            $(this).removeClass('open').addClass('close');
            $(this).children().children().html('-');
        }
    });
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/kac83/)

Answer (score 0):

you just need one `children()` there. since you span with `+` text is inside the clicked `<span>` (just a children of span)..

```
$(this).children().html('+');
```

try this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $("#switch").click(function(event){
    if ($("#navbar").css("display")=='block') {
        $("#navbar").hide('fast');
        $(this).removeClass('close').addClass('open');
        $(this).children().html('+');
    } else {
        $("#navbar").show('fast');
        $(this).removeClass('open').addClass('close');
        $(this).children().html('-');
    }
  });
});
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/kac83/2/)

Comment: Thank you but toggle state is not preserved on refresh